# DNS upstream IP not changing on dnsmasq with Netplan

Tags: server, dns, display-resolution, netplan, dnsmasq

I am running dnsmasq (Version: 2.80-1.1ubuntu1.5) on Ubuntu-20.04.04, the network interface is being managed by Netplan rendered inuse is networkd.

The DNSMasq forwards requests to the upstream nameserver IP as defined for the resolution.No issues till now.
But when I change nameserver IP and check status of dnsmasq, it still shows request being forwarded to old nameserver IP. I even tested after restarting the DNSmasq service and machine, but the issue still persists.

Any help on this is highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

++++Steps++++

```
`root@myserver:~# cat /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml | grep -A3 "nameservers"`

      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 10.0.3.2
        - 8.8.4.4

root@myserver:~# systemctl status dnsmasq | grep -i nameserver
Sep 06 10:43:40 myserver dnsmasq[1318]: using nameserver 10.0.3.2#53
root@myserver:~# vi /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml 
root@myserver:~# netplan apply
root@myserver:~# cat /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml | grep -A3 "nameservers"

      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 8.8.8.8
        - 8.8.4.4

root@myserver:~# systemctl status dnsmasq | grep -i nameserver
Sep 06 10:43:40 myserver dnsmasq[1318]: using nameserver 10.0.3.2#53   <-------- OLD UP STREAM IP IN USE
```

+++Netplan config+++

```
root@myserver:~# cat /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml 
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      addresses:
      - 10.45.3.25/24
      gateway4: 10.45.3.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 8.8.8.8
        - 8.8.4.4
root@myserver:~#
```

++++DNSMasq config+++

```
root@myserver:~# cat /etc/dnsmasq.conf | grep -v '#' |uniq
resolv-file=/etc/resolv.dnsmasq
listen-address=127.0.0.1,172.17.0.1
cache-size=1000
root@myserver:~#
```